# What will happen to reactance of an inductor with some value, if a permanent magnet is brought near it ?

Tags: electromagnetism

Change in value of inductor :
Change in value of reactance :
Formula to calculate it theoritically :

Answer (score 0):

The reactance of an inductor is $j\omega$. So it depends on the frequency of the current flowing through it.
Now if we bring a permanent magnet  near to it, the magnetic flux linked with the inductor coil will be changed. So a back emf will induced in the coil. But if we keep the permanent magnet in one place near the coil, the magnetic flux linked with the coil will not be changed since here the magnet is not in motion. So in this case there will be no induce emf.

Comment: So, when a back emf will induce in the inductor coil then the current following through it obviously reduce a bit. In that sense you can say the reactance is increased.